# asp.net Listbox Formatting not persisting after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ListBox that has highlighted items based on their status. If they are incomplete, they are colored red. After selecting one of the items from the list and displaying it's relate data, the coloring doesn't work. How can I keep this formatting persistent?

Code:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            MarkIncompleteList();
            DataTable dt = Data.GetOrderStatusTypes();

            ddlOrderStatusTypes.DataSource = dt;
            ddlOrderStatusTypes.DataTextField = "StatusName";
            ddlOrderStatusTypes.DataValueField = "StatusID";
            ddlOrderStatusTypes.DataBind();




            if (Request.QueryString["OrderID"] != "")
            {
                Data.GetOrderByNumber(ref currOrder, Request.QueryString["OrderID"]);
                DisplayOrderData();
            }
        }
        else
```

### MarkIncompleteList();

```
protected void MarkIncompleteList()
    {
        // get a list of orders that are not complete for allerting
        List<string> iOrders = Data.GetIncomepletedOrders();

        lbOrderID.Text = "";
        List<string> ol = Data.GetOrdersList();
        // add the order list to the list box change the color if its in the 
        // incomplete list
        foreach (string s in ol)
        {
            if (iOrders.Contains(s))
            {
                lbCurrentOrders.Items.Add(s);
                lbCurrentOrders.Items[lbCurrentOrders.Items.Count - 1].Attributes.Add("style", "color:red");

            }
            else
                lbCurrentOrders.Items.Add(s);
        }
    }
```

Comment: MarkIncompleteList();
 should be outside of "IsPostBack"

Comment: If I did that, the initial page load would not display the formatting. That needs to be there so it's formatted as soon as the page is loaded the first time.

Comment: Really, have you tried it?

Comment: lol... no. Not before I Responded. Sry. I just moved it and tried it. It is formatted initially, but after selecting an item to view the item details, the formatting still does not persist.

Comment: Try putting the MarkIncompleteList() outside the IsPostback and also putting a call to lbCurrentOrders.Items.Clear() at the start of MarkIncompleteList().

Comment: Thank you Martin. This is exactly what was causing the issue. However, putting the MarkIncompleteList() causes a null reference exception because the page load gets called before the MarkIncompleteList does and the item is no longer selected. I'm making the call Mark in the click event and it's working. MarkIncompleteList() makes two calls to the database, is there a more efficient way of getting this list and keeping the data to minimize the database traffic?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the stupid question and thank you everyone for your quick responses. The issue was related to the items in the list. I was NOT clearing the items after the selection. This caused my list to look normal but re-added the formatted list to the end of the original. I've corrected this and it's now working properly.

```
protected void MarkIncompleteList()
    {
        // remove the old items so the list is refreshed **************
        lbCurrentOrders.Items.Clear();
        // get a list of orders that are not complete for allerting
        List<string> iOrders = Data.GetIncomepletedOrders();

        lbOrderID.Text = "";
        List<string> ol = Data.GetOrdersList();
        foreach (string s in ol)
        {
            if (iOrders.Contains(s))
            {
                lbCurrentOrders.Items.Add(s);
                lbCurrentOrders.Items[lbCurrentOrders.Items.Count - 1].Attributes.Add("style", "color:red");

            }
            else
                lbCurrentOrders.Items.Add(s);
        }


    }
```